# Is it possible to hook up a hose to my well pump?

Tags: water, well-pump

I have a well pump that goes and pull water from an aquifer. I'd like to hook up a hose to it and water some plants that my sprinkler system cannot reach very well. Is it possible to do this?

Pictures of my well pump:

[image: Well Main]

The lever on towards the back controls lawn sprinklers and the one closer to me controls the back lawn sprinklers.

[image: Label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that is a small pressure tank (blue thing top of photo). 
The answer is yes yo can hook up a garden hose. I would add a valve so if the hose springs a leak you can turn it off. The next bit of good news it looks like you have 2 ports on the pressure side (top pipe right) if they unscrew add a hose bib and you can water all you want.

Comment: Alright one more question. How exactly do I relieve the pressure? According to the manual I found online that little box seems to control it. Do I just twist that and it will relive it or how do I do so? The manual is not very clear.

Comment: @Sie answering your question in the comment above: there's a pressure switch on that pump, to "relieve the pressure" so that the pump comes on just turn on the water, the water flows, pressure drops pump comes on.  To get the pump to stop turn of the water and wait, with that small of a storage tank it will likely cut off pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. It looks like you can even go off one of the Tees already conveniently installed. You'll need an adapter which will depend on the hose, but very simple to install.

Comment: Should I be good to go to hook it right up? I have a few questions... Any precautions I need to take? Also how exactly is the pump activated? Like would the pump go on/off every time I release the house handle?

Comment: the pump is pressure activated see the line from the pump to the electrical box. this is a pressure switch. When the pressure gets below the set point it turns the pump on when at cutoff point it turns the pump off.

Comment: @EdBeal Right. However would the frequent on/off be harmful to the pump?

Comment: the blue tank above I believe is a bladder based pressure tank it gives a few seconds of water use prior to turning the pump on, then allows the pump to run longer when set up properly.

Comment: @Sie excessive on/off cycles should be avoided. The pressure tank helps prevent this. basically, the bigger the tank the better, so use the biggest you can afford.The one you currently have may be a bit undersized, it depends on how much water you're planning on running through the system. That is, it will work to give you water at the pressure you want, but eventually the pump will die faster than it would with a larger tank.